# Click two images to show another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hopefully I explain this well :)

When 2 images are selected I want a different image to appear e.g. There are 6 plate options and 4 food options. Users will select a picture and food item and depending on what they have selected a picture with the plate and food will show.

I've searched and searched. What I am thinking is two have some javascript that says when two inputs (images) are selected show an image. e.g. Input: RED PLATE + Input: CHICKEN = RED PLATE WITH CHICKEN ON IT.

```html
<div class="mixMatch">
  <div id="result">result image goes here</div>
    <table>
                   
  <tr>
    <td id="plates">
    <div id='p1'><img src="../images/chapter7/Frame1_Clear.jpg"/></div>
    <div id='p2'><img src="../images/chapter7/Frames3_Clear.jpg"/></div>         
    <div id='p3'><img src="../images/chapter7/Frames4_Clear.jpg"/></div>
    <div id='p4'><img src="../images/chapter7/Frames8_Clear.jpg"/></div>
    </td>
    <td id="foods">
      <div id='f1'><img src="../images/chapter7/brownLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f2'><img src="../images/chapter7/greenLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f3'><img src="../images/chapter7/greyLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f4'><img src="../images/chapter7/emeraldLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f5'><img src="../images/chapter7/amethystLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f4'><img src="../images/chapter7/sapphireLenses.png"/></div>
      <div id='f4'><img src="../images/chapter7/amethystLenses.png"/></div>
     </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

I put the actual code I've done so far abouve. So when Frame1 and brownLens is selected it displays an image called "Frame1BrownLens.jpg".
Any help about how I can go about this?

Comment: `have some javascript` - yes, that's how you would go about it

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this? (with images instead of text, obviously)

(click on Run code snippet to play around)

```js
$('#plates div').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children().removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#result').text('Please select food');
});
$('#foods div').click(function(){
  let plate = $('#plates .selected').text();
  let food = $(this).text();
  $('#result').text('We have '+food+' in '+plate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#plates, #foods {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.selected {
  font-weight:700;
}
</style>
<div id="result">Please select a plate and a food</div>
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="20px">
<thead>
<th>Plates</th>
<th>Foods</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="plates">
<div id='p1'>Plate 1</div>
<div id='p2'>Plate 2</div>
<div id='p3'>Plate 3</div>
<div id='p4'>Plate 4</div>
<div id='p5'>Plate 5</div>
<div id='p6'>Plate 6</div>
</td>
<td id="foods">
<div id='f1'>Food 1</div>
<div id='f2'>Food 2</div>
<div id='f3'>Food 3</div>
<div id='f4'>Food 4</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes that basically what I mean. For some reason when I run this in my editor on my laptop it isn't working. I placed the script and css externally and it is all linked correctly. Also instead of it displaying a combined string, how would i get it to display an image.

Comment: Maybe Run code snippet does not work because your browser is blocking `iframe`s. I can't be 100% sure before I touch that laptop :)
As for showing an image instead of the text - the last line in JS could be changed to `$('#result').html('<img src="food'+food+'plate'+plate+'.jpg"'>);` and you could name your images as food1plate1.jpg, food2plate1.jpg, etc.